# function of effect fails with xlevels

Tags: r

I am working on developing a function, with the `effects` package in R. I am constantly running into a problem, which I can't debug.

I run the following code:

```
rm(list = ls())  # clear working directory
library(effects)

head(mtcars)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ gear*cyl + gear + cyl + carb, data=mtcars)
summary(mod)

eff.dat <- effect("gear*cyl", mod=mod, KR=TRUE, xlevels=list(gear=seq(3,5,1)))
eff.dat <- as.data.frame(eff.dat)
View(eff.dat)
```

It works like a charm, I get the effects for the interaction term on `mpg` when `gear` equals `3, 4,` and `5` and the corresponding values of `cyl`.

However, once I put this into a function like:

```
proba <- function(term, model, main) {
  
    eff.dat2 <<- effect(term, mod=model, KR=TRUE,
                     xlevels=list(main=seq(min(mtcars[[main]]),
                                           max(mtcars[[main]]), 1)))
    eff.dat2 <<- as.data.frame(eff.dat2)
}

proba("gear*cyl", model=mod, main="gear")

View(eff.dat2)
```

The `xlevels` part fails and the interaction term is estimated for the default values of `gear`, not the ones I specify. Obviously, this is part of a larger function, otherwise I would not bother to write something solely for `effect`.

Comment: Why are you creating a function without return value but rely on a side effect?

Comment: Also, use `setNames(list(seq(min(mtcars[[main]]),
                                           max(mtcars[[main]]), 1)), main)`. Your code uses `"main"` as the name of the list element.

Comment: Thanks, this works! I am happy to accept it should you write it up as an answer, however, I don't quite get why I need `setNames` there.

Comment: Given, in the code which works, effectively `main` is also used as the name of the list element (`gear`) and this seems to be what `xlevels` requires, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First an illustration what happens:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  list(x = x)
}

foo("bar")
#$x
#[1] "bar
```

Note how the list element is named `x`. `setNames` can be used to set names programmatically:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  setNames(list(x), x)
}

foo("bar")
#$bar
#[1] "bar"
```

Also, you should avoid creating function side effects with `<<-`. It's very bad practice. Create a proper return value instead:

```
proba <- function(term, model, main) {
  as.data.frame(
    effect(term, mod=model, KR=TRUE,
           xlevels= setNames(list(seq(min(mtcars[[main]]),
                                      max(mtcars[[main]]), 1)), main))
  )
}

eff.dat2 <- proba("gear*cyl", model=mod, main="gear")
all.equal(eff.dat, eff.dat2)
#[1] TRUE
```